# How to create table via ODBC in ansi sql compliant way?

Tags: sql, odbc

We want to export our data to unknown sql database. It could be mysql, mssql, postgresql. And even simple things create problems. For example, in MySQL double quotes for identifiers only work when ANSI_QUOTES = true (false by default). Double quotes in mssql only work when QUOTED_IDENTIFIER = ON. There are also some issues about HOW MySQL interprets sql compliant code. For example, sometimes it ignores explicitly specified constraint names and set name according it's rules. MS SQL also does not support data type named BLOB. Is there a smart way of doing sql compliant odbc export? Or somehow we have to query database name and configure connection in a way that makes it sql compatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SQLGetInfo** can be used to query **SQL_IDENTIFIER_QUOTE_CHAR** and it returns " for sql server in my config (as pointed out by Andrey Belykh in another short answer).

I use **SQLGetInfo** with **SQL_DBMS_NAME** parameter to get dbms name. In case of sql server it returns "Microsoft SQL Server". Then I can apply sql server specific code. SQL server way of storing *blob* is through *filestream*, but it has limitations (must use Windows authentication to access files). So in case blob is not supported (also can be checked by SQLGetTypeInfo) I use *varbinary(max)* which is limited by 2 gigabytes (that's ok for me, I ignore larger files). I cannot use varbinary by default because in mysql it is limited to 65KB. So AFAIK custom code is required to support different dbms.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for quoting identifiers you can use SQLGetInfo and ask for SQL_IDENTIFIER_QUOTE_CHAR